# javascript string - remove PHP instructions leaving only the HTML elements

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to repopulate the html DOM from a string that contains PHP and HTML code using js.

```
var string = "<?php echo Hi Friends ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/loader.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <?php echo Hi Friend ?>
  </body>
</html>";
```

Desired output:

```
var string = *strip away all php*;
var string = "<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/loader.js" defer></script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <p>Hello</p>
      </body>
    </html>";
window.body.innerHTML = string;
```

I would expect only the html code to be rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method that works:

1. Turn your string into an array by `.split()` on the endline char:

```
var arr = string.split('\n');
```

2. Loop through the array, using this regex to remove any PHP strings

```
let cln = arr[i].replace(/(.*)(<\?.*\?>)(.*)/, "$1$3");
```

3. Store each "cleaned" line into a new array

#### Explanation of the RegEx (step 2)

`()` - represents a "capture group" (each line will be split into three captured groups)

`(.*)` - the first group contains all the characters from the beginning UNTIL...

`(...)` - the 2nd capture group contains from `<?` to `?>` and all chars in between (i.e. a PHP string)

`(.*)` - the 3rd group contains any characters following a PHP string

`$1 $2 $3` - are the contents of the three capture groups

So, each line (as it is processed by the for loop) is split up into these three groupings of characters.

On MOST of the lines, groups 2 and 3 are empty. Group 1 is the entire line. So, returning group 1 and group 3 returns the entire line.

On lines that contain a PHP string, the PHP is in capture group 2 (which is never returned). Returning group 1 and group 3 either returns an empty string, or it might return some spaces that preceeded or followed the PHP string. So, we also use `.trim()` to remove those. If the line with spaces removed is zero-length, we do not include in the new (output) array.

```js
var htm = `<?php echo Hi Friends ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/loader.js" defer>  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <?php echo Hi Friend ?>
  </body>
</html>`;
//console.log(htm);
var out=[], arr=htm.split('\n');
for ( var i=0; i<(arr.length); i++ ){
  let cln = arr[i].replace(/(.*)(<\?.*\?>)(.*)/, "$1$3");
  //console.log(cln + ' - ' + cln.trim().length);
  if (cln.trim().length>0){
    out.push(cln.trim());
  }
}
console.log(out.join("\n") );
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will work for you using regex and the replace prototype. One note on the way your string is constructed, you will want to replace the quotations(") that they're wrapped with and substitute with the acute symbol(`)

```
string.replace(/\<\?php.*>/g,'');
```